# Remove files from central repo but keep in all local repos

Tags: git

We have some files in our git repo.
Now I want to remove it from remote repo, but keep local copies in all local developer's repos.
I've tried add files to `.gitignore`, then `git rm --cached` but after that files were removed from other develops repos.

## UPDATE

We have one shared `.gitignore` file. I've changed this file, commited, then run 'git rm --cached', commited, pushed. No success

Comment: May I ask why exactly you are trying to do this? If you want to remove sensitive data a `git rm --cached` won't suffice because the file still exists in the history.

Comment: If the goal is to delete heavy files, this won't suffice either (for the same reason: they're still in the history).

Comment: @Zeeker, Dettorer The reason is little strange) I've joined to team recently. And I found IDE files in repo. My teammates think it is not bad practices to store such files, but I don't. And now I want to remove it without affect on other developers

Comment: Are you sure that this shared `.gitignore` now matches the files you gave to `git rm --cached`? It's hard to tell without seeing the actual configuration, tree and `.gitignore`, can you reproduce this with a concrete example?

Comment: @ІгарЦімошка, this *will* affect them, their IDE files will not be versioned anymore, that could be troublesome if they still expect them to be.

Comment: @Dettorer Yes, I am sure. After commit I `git status` doesn't show this modified files

Comment: @Dettorer Yes, files will not be versioned. That is ok. We agreed it

Comment: I think I get it. The problem is that the `--cached` option you give to `git rm` only tells git to keep the file in *your* tree, but the commit created still just delete the file. Do you actually need to run `git rm` after updating the `.gitignore`? The only problem I see is that cloning this project will also clone the IDE files at the state they were before you updated the `.gitignore`. I admit this is annoying though. I think you're doing it right but need to tell the other devs to backup their files, pull, then put them back.

Comment: @Dettorer Yes, now it is my only solution. But I thought I can do it with git)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [sparse checkouts](http://briancoyner.github.io/blog/2013/06/05/git-sparse-checkout/). If they're not what you want, there's an alternative method:

you could create a local branch for your current "central branch" (presumably `master`), then work in the local branch and push relevant changes back to the team cenral branch as cherry-picks from your local branch. This is not that convenient, although the task of synchronizing "local" and "central" branches could be automated easily enough.